# "How to solve "SSL peer shut down incorrectly" when updating android studio

Tags: android-studio, updates

I updated my android studio from `2.1.2` to `2.1.3`. But after restart an error occurred with this message. "`SSL` peer shut down incorrectly". How can i solve it?

Comment: Did you resolved this issue? I am facing same issue with different Android studio version though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by some kind of incompatibility with HTTPS.

For solve this, in the Preferences,go to  Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK there are a tab called "SDK Update Sites", at the bottom of this section is the option "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."
and check the option "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...".