# SSL peer shut down incorrectly after upgrade android studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

After upgrade android studio 3.5, when I debug the app, say "SSL peer shut down incorrectly."

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to do a clean and rebuild on your project. If that does not work, it could be related to HTTPS handling. You can try some of the tips suggested [here] ([Error:SSL peer shut down incorrectly In Android studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629999/errorssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-in-android-studio-3-0-1)) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001013/how-to-solve-ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-when-updating-android-studio) for this problem.